# find a substring in a range

Tags: c++, c++98

im trying to find a substring in a range using the string::find method, the string is in range but its returning npos

code:

```cpp
std::cout << "find: \"" << find << "\"" << std::endl;
std::cout << "headerEnd: " << this->_headerEnd << std::endl;

size_t startPos = this->_request.find(find.c_str(), 0);
std::cout << "startPos1: " << startPos << std::endl;

startPos = this->_request.find(find.c_str(), 0, this->_headerEnd);
std::cout << "startPos2: " << startPos << std::endl;
```

output:

```bash
find: "Content-Type: "
headerEnd: 641
startPos1: 294
startPos2: 18446744073709551615
```

from my understanding, the second find should return the same value, as it is searching from 0 to 641 (headerEnd) and the string is located at 294 being only 14 characters long

so why is it returning npos? ive tried changing from c++98 to c++11 and still gives me the same output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstood the behavior of the second function. Please read the [doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)(2).

What the function really do is find substring of `s` in range [s, s + count) in the object calling the function start from `pos`. Here is a small example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::string;

int main() {
  string str = "abc123bcd";
  cout << (str.find("123321", 0, 3)) << std::endl;
}
```

which outputs `3`. `str.find("123321", 0, 3)` means, find the substring of `123321` of range [0, 3), which is `123` in `str`.

In your code, it means search the substring of `find.c_str()` of length `this->_headerEnd` in `this->_request`, which is 641, far more than the real size 14. Which makes your search failed.

Comment: @gsistelos Use print to find there the bug is is a very inefficient method. Read the doc or use a debugger is usually a better choice. And you can also ask stackoverflow community like this

Comment: thank you, it actually makes more sense this way
i can just use find and check if (startPos > this->_headerEnd)

Comment: @gsistelos `if (startPos == npos)` is usually a better choice, both in terms of readability and security

Comment: checking if its in the range i want (0 to this->_headerEnd) with `if (startPos >= this->_headerEnd)` means that it was not found or found after the range, so i can handle the case there

Comment: @gsistelos Yes, I knew what you mean. If `find` did not find, it returns `npos`, which is defined as [`static constexpr size_type npos = size_type(-1);`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/npos). If you use the expression you showed above, you are asking the register to parse a signed integer as an unsigned integer, then compare it with your string size. Though it actually works for `-1` parsed as unsigned integer is the maximum value, it is still kinda weird and I can't tell if this will go wrong in some special cases